# Change the width of a div when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have no idea what goes wrong with my code but it gives me errors every time I click the blue `Chat Here`  button. The button's supposed to be shorter when the `iframe` is hidden then when the `iframe` slides up, the blue button should take up the whole space the same as the `iframe` as well.

[View Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cmzwx)

Here's the JS I have so far

```
function showChat() {
    jQuery("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        jQuery("#blk-collaboration #toggle").css("background","#45A1F1");
    });

    jQuery('#btn-chat').click(function() {
        $(this)//this is a button DOM element. wrapping in jQuery object.
       .toggleClass('wide'); // removing wide class so button became smaller.
    });
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chatbox').hide();
});
```

I'd greatly appreciate if you could provide me a demo as well. Been working on this code for two days now and I haven't found the right solution yet.

Comment: Why do you put the click handler of `#btn-chat` inside of `showChat()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forget to put `;` on your height property. Another important thing is that you need to change your class position like this:

```
.button {
  background: #45A1F1; 
  height: 40px;
  width: 620px; /*Width of regular button */ 
}
.wide { 
  background: #45A1F1; 
  height: 40px;
  width:  300px; !important; /* Width of wide button */ 
}
```

You can simplify your code by using this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chatbox').hide();
    $('#btn-chat').click(function() {
        $("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        $("#blk-collaboration #toggle").css("background","#45A1F1");
    });
      $(this)//this is a button DOM element. wrapping in jQuery object.
      .toggleClass('wide'); // removing wide class so button became smaller.
    });
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj8LobkL/)..